# Backup LaCie 5big Pro to Amazon Glacier

Tags: backup, nas, rsync, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know of an easy way that I could back-up my LaCie 5big Pro NAS to Amazon Glacier? The automatic backup feature of the LaCie only supports rsync compatible servers, which Amazon Glacier is not. Alternatively, if someone knows of a similar service to Amazon Glacier which is rsync compatible, that would be helpful as well.

I'm currently looking to back up my company's files for a disaster recovery situation, so files will continuously be added, but not so much retrieved.

Thanks

Comment: I found this by doing a Google search on the term `rsync amazon glacier` http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/rsync-backups-to-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ Not exactly the "rsync" solution you are looking for, but this is the closest. ]

While doing my research for own personal backup solution I came across

[Cloudberry Desktop](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-cloud-desktop-backup.aspx) software.

It supports Amazon Glacier (and many other popular storage backends).

You should be able to run this software on your PC and backup the NAS drive (which I assume are mounted as a network drive on the PC) to Amazon Glacier.

For me, personally, I couldn't use this software for a couple of reasons, but it may work for you.